# Should munin be password-protected?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, security, munin

We use Munin at work.
There is a Munin install  - which right now is open to the world.
An admin doesn't think he needs to password-protect it.

What's the worst that can happen? How can I convince the boss to convince admin to pasword-protect it?

Comment: By "*munin install open to the world*", I take it you mean that the web server that serves the results is open, not that the individual munin nodes are?

Comment: It should be an internally facing web app. What's the point of broadcasting to the world?

Comment: Externally facing or internally (corporate network only)?

Comment: Admin can limit the IPs that can access the Munin web page if he doesn't want to bother with a password but it's not a good idea to have munin info exposed to the Internet at large, you are giving out info and potential attack ideas

Answer (score 2):

A DDOS attacker could easily see how much effect his different methods have for different aspects of your server or infrastructure before it has reached any critical point.

He would also get an overview of servers that may not be easily obtained otherwise to strengthen his knowledge about your infrastructure before an attack.

He would also be able to see some information about services running on your servers (with a good munin setup..) to see potential attack targets.

Competitors would get information about your traffic patterns.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to disagree.  I'm not over-impressed by the idea that every single piece of information that leaks about my infrastructure exposes an attack surface.  It's mindless security-through-obscurity: if your security relies on keeping your network diagram secret, you're probably doing it wrong.  Assume that an attacker is going to know all this stuff, and design your network to be secure *even when they do*.

Yes, there is some stuff that should be secret; but it's a short list, and should be closely guarded.  If you simply chuck every piece of internal information onto that list, you won't know what's really important, and you'll either over-react when something trivial leaks, or (more likely, and potentially worse) under-react when something important gets out.

That said, I (unsurprisingly) see no harm in exposing your munin graphs.  I do it myself; you can see them at http://www.teaparty.net/munin/teaparty.net/lory.teaparty.net/index.html , and I have quite often found it useful to link one or more graphs into my answers here on SF.  It's useful for people to have some idea of what sort of loads / uptimes / entropy pool depths / NTP sync states / whatever other people are seeing on their production gear.